Prove a series is uniformly convergent, hence continuous.
Question: Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(ne^{-nx})$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.
What I have tried: Since $ne^{-nx}$ is continuous for all $x>0$, it suffices to prove the uniform convergence of the series. I have tried the follow applications of the Weistrass M-test:
$ne^{-nx}=\frac{n}{e^{nx}}<\frac{n}{nx}=\frac{1}{x}$
and
$ne^{-nx}=\frac{n}{e^{nx}}<\frac{2n}{n^2x^2}=\frac{2}{nx^2}$
but in both cases, there is a residual $\frac{1}{x^k}$ that prevents me from using the M-test for the whole positive real axis. Is there another way I can use the M-test? Or must I prove it by definition? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and apply the $M$-test on $(\epsilon,\infty)$ to deduce continuity here. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves continuity on $(0,\infty)$. But anyway, neither of your estimates is good enough; you need something summable in $n$, so you should try to prove atleast $1/n^2$ decay (actually you have exponential decay so that’s much stronger).

Thank you so much!
Just to make sure, if I take an arbitrary  and consider the range $(,\infty)$ and the inequality $ne^{-nx}=\frac{n}{e^{-nx}}<\frac{6n}{n^{3}x^{3}}<\frac{6}{n^{2}^{3}}$ then the series converges by p-test and M-test right?

Yes that’s right. And in fact a similar argument shows the function is $C^{\infty}$ (the key point being that on $(\epsilon,\infty)$, the exponential decay in $n$ trumps all the polynomial growth coming from the derivatives).

@Anne Bauval sorry but I am not sure this answers my question at this moment cuz I am now only studying real analysis and would like to stick to methods i can use in real analysis! but thank you for your recommendation i will look into this question if i take complex analysis in the future! thanks

@peek-a-boo Ahh icic. Thanks so much for clarifying some of the key concepts :))

You don't need complex analysis to understand that solution. Simply perform the change of variable $y=e^{-x}$ and study the convergence of the more usual series $\sum ny^n$ on $(-1,1)$

The latter converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$ for every positive $r<1$ because  $ \sum nr^n<\infty$, for instance
by the ratio test.
